# How to use a Python 3 socket client/server setup over the internet (not locally)?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to implement a simple chat program that uses sockets to transmit data via a UDP connection. However, I can't figure out how to correctly set it up so that people from outside my local network can access it if I am hosting it on my laptop. I am utilizing port 5000, and have port-forwarded that port on my router for my laptop. The port-forwarding doesn't seem to be the issue; at least the "Port Forward Network Utilities" from portforward.com seems to detect it as properly forwarded. Maybe I am mixing up the IP addresses I need to host from and connect with? The code in question is below:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys


class Server:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connections = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(('192.168.1.5', 5000))
        self.sock.listen(1)

    def handler(self, c, a):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            for connection in self.connections:
                print(data.decode())
                connection.send(data)
            if not data:
                break

    def run(self):
        while True:
            c, a = self.sock.accept()
            cThread = threading.Thread(target=self.handler, args=(c, a))
            cThread.daemon = True
            cThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)
            print(self.connections)


class Client:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    usr_name = ""

    def sendMsg(self):
        while True:
            self.sock.send(bytes(self.usr_name + ": " + input("-> "), 'utf-8'))

    def __init__(self, address):
        self.sock.connect((address, 5000))
        self.usr_name = input("Enter a username: ")
        iThread = threading.Thread(target=self.sendMsg)
        iThread.daemon = True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            data = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data.decode())


if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    client = Client(sys.argv[1])
else:
    server = Server()
    server.run()
```

As you can see, I have my current local IP address inputted for hosting the server, while the client asks for an IP to connect to. I'm not sure what to do now for hosting this over the internet, but I have tried every IP combination I can think of and it returns a number of errors.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
The two main errors I was getting are:

- Timeout Error [WinError 10060]

  - My friend received this when trying to connect from another network
- [WinError 10061]

  - I would receive this when trying to connect using my public IP from the same computer

I'm sorry that I can't be more detailed in my errors and provide a full printout, and I will try to update this if I'm able to replicate them.

Edit:
**I was able to rewrite it and get it to work, I don't need anymore help with this. 
Thanks.**

Comment: You have to give the client the public IP address of your router. Is that one of the IPs you've tried? Also, the server should be fine with its LAN address, but it should also be fine with `0.0.0.0`, which is simpler, portable, less likely to be typo'd, etc.'

Comment: Meanwhile, "a number of errors" isn't something that anyone can debug. If you don't tell us exactly which errors you get from which combination (or, more importantly, give us the complete error traceback for the sensible combination, but you might not have known that until now), we can't debug it.

Comment: One last thing: Are you sure you forwarded UDP 5000 to 5000, as opposed to TCP 5000 to 5000, or UDP 5000 to some arbitrary port, or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're port-forwarding UDP port 5000 to 5000.

But you're opening TCP streams, not UDP. That's what `SOCK_STREAM` means. If you want UDP, you need to use `SOCK_DGRAM`.

So, you need to make these two consistent. The only problem is, I'm not sure which one you actually want here.

On the one hand, your code is doing connection-oriented `recv`, and seems to be assuming reliable transmission, which means you probably want TCP.

On the other hand, your code seems to be assuming that each `recv(1024)` is going to get exactly one `send` from the other side, which is only true for UDP; [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html). When you do a `recv(1024)`, you could easily get just the first 12 bytes of an 80-byte line, which means it could end in the middle of a UTF-8 character, which means `decode` will throw an exception.

I think you want TCP, but with a framing protocol on top of it. The simplest protocol that would probably make sense here is lines of text. Which is pretty easy to do on your own, but even easier to do with `socket.makefile`, given that you're dedicating a thread to each connection.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers, it helps a lot. I tried to give the errors above but I don't have the full traceback on hand and it may take me awhile to replicate the errors in order to get them. I am very new to network programming (as you can probably tell) but thank you so much for your help. I'm going to try and implement the changes you listed above now, and probably stick with UDP.

Comment: @DesperateConcept You must have some reason you thought you wanted UDP instead of TCP. I'm just trying to guess what makes sense here; you ought to actually know what you were actually trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I'm probably going to just try and rewrite the code with some of the tips you provided. It looks like my problem was probably centered around TCP vs UDP and how I was handling the sockets rather than the IPs like I originally thought. Thanks again.